# tracking clicks by device/ os in tag manager/ google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a link in the header of my website which takes users to the 'my account' page. 

On a full screen desktop browser the link is is a small icon and the text 'my account' next to it (using ':)' to represent the icon btw) i.e. 

`:) my account`.

On a mobile or tablet (smaller screen), only the icon appears and not the words. i.e.

 
`:)`

To conserve screen space.


I want to see whether I have put the my 'account link' in a good place. And whether people notice only the icon, when on mobile or tablet. 

I plan to measure this by seeing how many times the 'my account' link is clicked and split up the clicks by device/os. 

For example i might find, lots of people click the 'my account' link on the desktop site, but hardly anyone clicks it in comparison on IOS or any other mobile device e.g. android. 

Thus showing it perhaps isn't as noticeable or is confusing when i only display the icon without the text on small screens.


Does anyone know how i can achieve this in tag manager/ google analytics.
I previously set up tags that track page views and virtual page views(using datalayer variables) so have some experience with tag manager V2. 


(as an aside is there a way to tell whether a click has come from a mobile or tablet also?)


Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way to do this is to set a simple GTM tag with firing rule - click on the element you want to track (by class or id or whatever you wish), send the clicks data as events in Google Analytics and review the event with secondary dimension device category (which is mobile/desktop/tablet), or even device name/model. You can create a custom report for this to be easier to access everytime.

So - 1st - set a new GTM Tag - type Universal Analytics, Event, and fill the "Event category" as "my-account clicks" (just an example).
Look at the source code of your site, and see if the link have an id to use (for example - id="my-account"). Set a firing rule on clicks - some clicks - element id equals my-account. That's all actually, the clicks will send an event to GA. You can get some more info to be sent with the event, like setting event action - "Clicked on: {{url}}", to give you information on what page the user clicked the link. You can play also with the firing rule, but that's the basic setup.

Once you are done you can test it with Real-Time, under events.

Later, when you collect enough info - just go to events in your GA, under behavior, click on the "my-account clicks" and set a secondary dimension - device category.

Comment: So i set up the device recognition in GA. I had a play around today and was using custom javascript variables to pass information about the user's device as part of the tag, when it fires. Im guessing this is unnecessary, and you merely fire an event, and then use GAs cleverness to filter by device and os?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. My experience showed GA is pretty good at recognizing these by himself (tested it some time ago with changing my build.prop file to various devices).

Comment: awesome! i just set up what you described. In about 5 mins work i have it tracking clicks on that link by device. I just spent a whole day rolling out my own solution lol DOH! :( Thanks for the help. I guess i never really understood what GA can do and how it handles things sent from GTM. Just been finding it hard to find good resources or places where people talk about GTM and GA. Thanks again for your help, been very useful and i've learned alot

Comment: always welcome :) and sadly - there are really not enough resources around, especially for GTM. By the way Simo Ahava have great resources and ideas, it's a must for everyone dealing with GTM (http://www.simoahava.com/)

Comment: i noticed Simo Ahava whilst googling around, seems to be a good resource (maybe the only good resource). I find GTM and GA very unintuitive to begin with, but is starting to become a little simpler now i've got my head round it. I feel like google could make the whole thing a little more obvious and straightforward (it seems unnecessarily messy atm). It doesn't help that a lot of tutorials on the web refer to the previous incarnation of GTM either (which seems to be a very different set up)